# Unspecified error occurs when installing SSDT for Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I'm upgrading from Visual Studio 2012 to 2013 for MSBI.

I have downloaded Visual Studio 2013 and SSDT separately.
SSDT fails to install:

> Unspecified error. One or more issues caused setup to fail. Please
>   fix the issues and then retry setup.

It creates a log file every time.

Comment: Why not give some key excerpts from the log?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop Business Intelligence projects, what you need is SSDT-BI, not SSDT. SSDT is for SQL Server database projects and publishing etc.

> SSDT-BI is for BI projects such as Integration Services, Reporting Services and Analysis Services.
>   You can download SSDT-BI 2013 from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=42313).

If you want it only for business intelligence projects you don't need to download Visual Studio separately, SSDT-BI comes with Visual Studio shell.

You can as well start using SSDT-BI 2015 which supports SQL Server 2016 too.


Good luck.